# Is it possible to remove a dependency from the Pipfile.lock file and keep other dependencies?

Tags: python, dependencies, circular-dependency, pipenv, pipfile

I have been trying to remove a dependency from a build and it continues to install even when it is not specified in the Pipfile (i.e: `depdendency = "*"`). I can say `pipenv uninstall dependency` , but that will uninstall it from the venv not the Pipfile.lock file. If anyone knows how to solve this issue I will be all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can manually remove the lines from your Pipfile then run

```
pipenv update 
pipenv clean
```

the update will update your Pipfile.lock
then the clean will remove the installed dependencies